# why does it say time limit exceeded when passed by value and works fine when passed by reference (lambda) c++

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> maxSlidingWindow(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        int i;
        auto comp = [&nums](int a, int b){return nums[a]<nums[b];};
        priority_queue<int,vector<int>,decltype(comp)> p(comp);
        for(i=0;i<k;i++){
            p.push(i);
        }
        vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(nums[p.top()]);
        for(i;i<nums.size();i++){
            p.push(i);
            while(p.top()<=i-k)p.pop();
            v.push_back(nums[p.top()]);
        }
        return v;
    }
```

above code works fine in leetcode and is accepted but when i change the lambda function to

`[nums](int a, int b){return nums[a]<nums[b];};`

it says TLE

Comment: Welcome to SO! Well, that copies the whole vector unnecessarily, adding a whole `n` multiplier to every PQ comparator operation.

Comment: What do you think happens when you take a `vector` by value?  How many copies do you think get made?

Comment: I case (2) every copy of `comp` has it's own copy of `nums` - there is no limit on how many times `std::priority_queue` will copy the comparison function. Comparison function are intended to be light-weight.

Comment: This is another case where you can't learn C++ from leetcode.  That's not its purpose.  An elementary course or good book in C++ would have stated that passing by value incurs a copy.

Comment: okay, but even if vector is copied it is order of n and even if that's a problem then shouldn't it say size limit exceeded.

Comment: @nerd -- You're asking us about the internals of leetcode.  We have no idea what it will do.

Comment: so does the array gets copied every time it's comapring?

Comment: @nerd you would need to inspect the source code of your systems implementation of `std::priority_queue`  Note that in case (2)  `nums` has already been copied twice by the time you declare `p`

Comment: @StephenNewell is it one copy of array, every time it compares?

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks, now it clarifies